# How can I have a function with interface input parameter and interface of same type return value?

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to implement a function in my utility package for pagination of slices with any types of slice given. It is supposed to accept an slice of interfaces plus the page and pagesize and must return an interface of the same type.

However, when I try to use the function I get the error that my input does not match the
`interface{}` input

> cannot use result (variable of type []entity.Something) as []interface{} value in argument to utility.PaginateSlice compilerIncompatibleAssign

Here is my function:

```
// PaginateList, paginates a slice based upon its page and pageSize.
func PaginateSlice(x []interface{}, page, pageSize int) []interface{} {
    var maxSize int = len(x)

    start := (page - 1) * pageSize
    end := start + pageSize - 1

    if start > maxSize || page < 1 || pageSize < 1 {
        start = 0
        end = 0
    } else if end > maxSize {
        end = maxSize
    }

    return x[start:end]
}
```

and here is an example of me trying to use it leading to failure:

```
var result []entity.Something

tmps := utility.PaginateSlice(dataOfSomethingType, pagination.Page, pagination.PageSize)
for _, tmp := range tmps {
    if value, ok := tmp.(entity.Something); ok {
    result = append(result, value)
}
```

Comment: Type `interface{}` is an interface type that is implemented by any type. However type `[]interface{}` is **NOT an interface type**, and therefore cannot be implemented by anything but itself. Type `[]entity.Something` is not, and never will be, assignable to `[]interface{}`. You either need to manually, element by element, convert the slice (see [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface)); Or you need to start using generics.

Comment: @mkopriva I see. Understandable. just wanted to check if there is any workarounds for this problem. What Im doing now is giving my function the result pointer and fill it inside the function itself. Not sure if its the way to GO but works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [type parameters](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations):

```
func PaginateSlice[S ~[]T, T any](x S, page, pageSize int) S {
    // insert body of function from question here
}
```